# In jQuery, remove tr in a table after a click

Tags: jquery

I've this type of table:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="number">
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" data-action="remove-item">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

By clicking on the 'remove-item', I want to remove the current `<tr>`.

Here what I've tried:

```
$('[data-action="remove-item"]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('td').closest('tr').remove();
})
```

But sometimes it doesn't work.

Why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`.closest()` function will find the element that you want to remove. So you don't need to use it twice.

[Jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) says below about the `.closest()` function.

> Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied
> selector

```js
$('[data-action="remove-item"]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number"> 1
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" data-action="remove-item">
                remove
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number"> 2
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" data-action="remove-item">
                remove
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="number"> 3
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" data-action="remove-item">
                remove
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#YourTableId").on('click','[data-action="remove-item"]',function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
```